# Asp.Net Core Web Api : Read Nlog config from App.config file Not loading target

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, nlog

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
    </configSections>
    <nlog internalLogFile="c:\Utilities\internal_log_file.txt">
        <extensions>
            <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
        </extensions>
        <targets>
            <target name="logfile"  xsi:type="file" fileName="C:/Utilities/${shortdate}_log.txt" layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${message}"/>
        </targets>
        <rules>
            <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
        </rules>
    </nlog>
</configuration>
```

I am not able to read the Config from App.config where in when I try to read from nlog.config it works.

I am trying to have a common config file which can be stored at common location and other api can also load the same config or log rather than having config file for each api separately.